# Loading KML file with ESRI javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, kml

I am trying to load a kml file using the ESRI javascript API v. 3.5.  What I did with v. 2.6 no longer works.  How do you add KML data with the latest esri javascript api?  I am testing on my local machine, which used to work fine.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/esri/css/esri.css"> 

        <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }
      body {
        background-color:#FFF;
        overflow:hidden;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
      }
    </style>

        <script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/"></script>
        <script>
            dojo.require("esri.map");
            dojo.require("esri.layers.KMLLayer");

            function init() {
              var beginExt = new esri.geometry.Extent(-81.26, 40.64, -74.10, 42.29, new esri.SpatialReference({wkid:4326}));
              var revExt = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(beginExt);
              var map = new esri.Map("map",{
                basemap:"topo",
                extent:revExt,
                sliderStyle:"small"
              });

              var kmlurl = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56614088/PA_Hospitals_2010.kmz";
              var kml = new esri.layers.KMLLayer(kmlurl);
              map.addLayer(kml);

            }

            dojo.ready(init);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="info"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the console I get an error

> Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This seemed to work fine with the older api why the difference?  How can we test locally since kml files have to be a public url without running a server?

**EDIT**

I ended up installing IIS on Windows 8.  I then used localhost.  In Chrome it would not work still gave me an error of

> Origin ...localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

So I tried IE again and it worked with localhost once I enabled intranet settings.  However, I did discover if you use the computer name ie.. http:// computername instead of localhost it will work in chrome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to set up a local web server so that you load your page over http://, not file://. More info:  http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/intro_devenv.html

Answer (score 3):

To view the kml from the link in dropbox, you'll have to set up a proxy page ([link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jshelp/ags_proxy.html)). When v. 3.4 came out, I noticed the api became more stringent about the cross origin issues. If your browser supports [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), but dropbox won't allow sharing with all sites (including localhost), then the content is blocked without a proxy.

Also, check what browser you're testing with. There have been issues where [Google Chrome won't support localhost on CORS requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892392/1190256). Double-check with Internet Explorer 9 or 10, which does support it.

But in general, the best way to get around it is by using the proxy page (plus using the [addProxy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/namespace_esri.html#addproxyrule) function found in 3.5 to make your browser use the proxy to get the kml).